# Save temporary history via script

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-history

I want to save the temporary history to a file via script. In the bash it works like that:

```
history -a /tmp/tmp_history
```

But if I add this line to my script, the tmp_history is empty. I use it like this in the script

```
#!/bin/bash
history -a /tmp/tmp_history
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `history -a  > /tmp/tmp_history`

Comment: does not work, it is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output to `tmp_history`: `history > /tmp/tmp_history` or try with `history -w /tmp/tmp_history`

Comment: that's not the way i want, i edited my first comment. i want to get the history of my active session and then save it via the script and do some more stuff. i need this because i do an api call with the changes i did on the system. that's why i want the session history.

Comment: `-a` option appends to `~/.bash_history`;